# Image popup wrapper/module for DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I'm using DNN 5 for a hobby site.  I know asp.net development, but have never written a DNN module.

The site is basically a project log.  I want content areas that combine text and image thumbnails in a page, like a set of instructions.  When a user clicks a thumbnail, display a popup div containing a larger image modal like on a lot of sites these days.   Basically I'm looking to wrap each image in functionality like provided by highslide JS, but I can't figure out the right way to implement highslide JS in DNN.

I'm not averse to buying a module that does this for me, but everything I've found is more gallery based.  The main difference is I want to control individual images that are among/next to the text, not a set of of images for users to scroll through.

I figure this can't be too crazy an idea, someone must have done it before.   Any tips on good approaches would be appreciated.    I'm tempted just to go edit source, but that makes upgrading a pain...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for this functionality, there's a project on Codeplex which looks pretty good at least as a gallery for DNN.    It implements the highslide type popups well.

http://wnslightbox.codeplex.com/documentation